# Condensing repetitive if statements

Tags: c#, if-statement, repeat

I have the following code, which scans a directory and puts files containing "a" within its filename to a new folder A. Similarly, it puts files with "b" within its filename to a new folder called B. Since the if statements are basically the same, with the only thing that changes being the letter "a" or "b" and being sent to either destA or destb (desitinations), how can I trim this code down? I know there is a better way because much of the code is repeated... Thanks.

```
static void Main()
{
    string path = @"C:\Users\me\Desktop\FOLDER";
    string destA = @"C:\Users\me\Desktop\FOLDER\A";
    string destB = @"C:\Users\me\Desktop\FOLDER\B";

    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    FileInfo[] filesxx = dir.GetFiles();
    foreach (FileInfo filexx in filesxx)
    {
        if (filexx.Name.Contains("a"))
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(destA))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destA);
            Console.WriteLine(filexx);
            filexx.CopyTo(Path.Combine(destA, filexx.Name), true);
        }
        else if (filexx.Name.Contains("b"))
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(destB))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destB);
            Console.WriteLine(filexx);
            filexx.CopyTo(Path.Combine(destB, filexx.Name), true);
        }　
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Other: ", filexx);
        }
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: Well, you could start with a subroutine, for all the duplicate code.  Then figure out how to construct the destA/destB pathnames rather than having to hard code them.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method like:

```
private Boolean MoveFile(FileInfo filexx, String nameMatch, String destDirectory) {
  Boolean result = false;
  if (filexx.Name.Contains(nameMatch)) {
    if (!Directory.Exists(destDirectory)) {
      Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirectory);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(filexx);
    filexx.CopyTo(Path.Combine(destDirecotry, filexx.Name), true);
    result = true;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Then just call it as necessary.

```
foreach(FileInfo filexx in filesxx) {
  if (!MoveFile(filexx, "a", destA)) {
    if (!MoveFile(filexx, "b", destB)) {
      Console.WriteLine("Other: ", filexx);
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, there is a potential precedence issue here.  What if the file is named "abcd"?  Should it go to the `A` folder or the `B` folder?

Comment: In the same line of logic as your parting question, would a file named "dcba" go into the same folder?

Comment: @CodeHxr: Exactly.  Doing a "contains" for a single letter within a file name sounds a bit *off*.  I'm hoping the code has simply been anonymized enough that what looks like a real problem isn't really.  If not, then I suspect that maybe he wants `StartsWith` instead of `Contains`

Answer (score 0):

If all you're looking for is less code, this should do it.

```
   public static void Main()
        {
            const string TargetPath = @"C:\Users\me\Desktop\FOLDER";
            var dir = new DirectoryInfo(TargetPath);
            var files = dir.GetFiles();
            foreach (var file in files.Where(file => !CopyFile(TargetPath, file, "a")).Where(file => !CopyFile(TargetPath, file, "b")))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Other: " + file.Name);
            }

            Console.Read();
        }

        private static bool CopyFile(string dir, FileInfo file, string match)
        {
            if (!file.Name.Contains(match))
            {
                return false;
            }

            dir = dir + "\\" + match.ToUpper();
            if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(file);
            file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(dir, file.Name), true);
            return true;
        }
```